# Как получить файлы с памяти телефона? java

Tags: java, android, файлы

Когда я пытаюсь получить файлы с какой-то директории в телефоне, к примеру "/storage/emulated/0" следующая функция возвращает null.

```java
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

Хотя на эмуляторе это работает без проблем, а ещё это работает если попытаться читать .../Android/data/com.test.test (папка приложения). Могу ли я как-то исправить это?

Comment: На новых версиях ОС без танцев с бубном получить доступ за пределы папки приложения не получится. Попробуйте посмотреть доку про ScopedStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это

```
File dir= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Путь");
```

Потом можете вывести все файлы из указанного пути, куда вам удобно
например таким способом:

```
File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
        String[] theNamesOfFiles = new String[filelist.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < theNamesOfFiles.length; i++) {
            theNamesOfFiles[i] = filelist[i].getName();
```